# Python .so files from cython generated .c files?

Tags: python, cython

I have generated .so and .c files using cython from python .pyx files.
Now I want to use .c files for distributing my code, so I tried to make .so files from .c files. And it was successful, but the problems is with importing .so files from python. 
    `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(
    ext_modules = [Extension("config", ["config.c"])]
)
```

I get the following error when importing:

```
import config

Error: dynamic module does not define init function (initconfig)
```

Everything works fine with the .so file generated from .pyx file.

Comment: A guess but - is it accidently managing to include Python3 headers instead of the Python2 ones? That would cause the module init function to have a slightly different name (`PyInit_config` instead of `initconfig`)? If you're using linux you could try running `objdump -t config.so | grep "nit"` and see what comes up.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have solved the problem, there some some naming mismatches

Comment: @n30 I'm facing the same problem. What were the naming mismatches you encountered?